# Converter didn't fired when the key is defined for background propety setter value in WinRT

Tags: winrt-xaml, converters

Can anyone help this when i used this in WPF ,its working fine. But in WinRT it didn't invoked the converter

```
<Application.Resources>
    <local:ConverterClass x:Key="converter"/>
    <Style TargetType="Grid:GridRowHeaderCell">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource converter }}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no Default support for setter binding in WinRT instead you can have a work around suggested in other sites , may be the link am gonna attach might help you

Link : https://aventuraspuntonet.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/mixing-style-setters-and-bindings-in-winrt/